# Swift CHARTS library how to change the legend colour to reflect Bar chart colour

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I am using CHARTS library in swift. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts and tutorial from the link https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/ on how to customise to suit your needs.

I am trying to change the Bar chart colour using the commands below as listed in the tutorial. While the bar chart colour changes correctly but the 'legend' colour listed below the bar chart is not updated. Can some suggest how to change the legend colour to reflect the bar chart.

2 different commands suggested in the tutorial, first one to change all the bars to one single colour and second to change to multiple colours. Both works fine for changing bar chart colour but NOT the legend.

```
chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 126/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)]
chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you should refer to the android documentation.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend

That one says:

> you can retreive the Legend object from the chart using the
>   getLegend() method

Then you will have access to methods that modify the way legends look.

> Styling / modifying the legend
>
> setTextColor(int color): Sets the color of the legend labels.
>   setTextSize(float size): Sets the text-size of the legend labels in
>   dp. setTypeface(Typeface tf): Sets a custom Typeface for the legend
>   labels.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 5 + general color change

```
BarChartView.legend.textColor = UIColor.white
```

if you want to give some special format , you can refer to

[Formatting Custom Legend Entries in Chart's PieChartView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204795/formatting-custom-legend-entries-in-charts-piechartview)